# How much was R2-D2 damaged by Darth Vader during the battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, r2-d2

R2-D2 survived a direct shot by Darth Vader during the assault on the first Death Star. (Not sure how somebody as Force powerful and skilled a pilot as Darth Vader could have missed blowing the X-Wing fighter apart instead of merely nicking a mere astromech droid, but hey, we'll go with this.)

R2 comes back all beat up and C-3PO promises to gladly donate some of its circuits.

How much damage did R2 receive during the battle?

Was its "brain" destroyed and many (all?) of its memories zapped?

Comment: His head was just blown off a little, it's all good.

Comment: @Jeff Next, somebody is going to tell me it was just a flesh wound.

Comment: Given that one of R2D2's data ports was in the head...I'd be tempted to say it was just a Flash wound

Comment: @AndrewTice *slow clap*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on what we see of what's in R2D2's dome, the answer seems to be very little important is in there. In other words, it's not his "head". It's unlikely they would leave it so exposed in the back of an X-Wing if it were

What we do see is

1. A radar dish of some sort
   [image]
2. A periscope
   [image]
3. A hidden compartment Luke hides his lightsaber in
   [image]
4. Apparently the dark dome is his camera. He swivels this in canon to face what he's looking at.
5. A holoprojector
   [image]
6. Various equipment to grab things. Most notably he can repair an X-Wing and serve drinks
   [image]

What we don't see displayed here are core (mission critical) systems. Moreover, there wouldn't be a lot of room for said systems with so much crammed in there. Presumably, R2D2 was blind from having the dome destroyed. Possibly whatever circuits that he uses to communicate. But the core was clearly undamaged. Only his utility would have been affected.

Comment: Making R2-D2 serve drinks was a waste of his talents. It's like telling a rocket scientist at NASA to get a job as a cocktail waitress.

Comment: Jabba the Hut didn't exactly care about wasting R2's talents

Comment: In Episode III (yes, I know), Obi-wan's droid R4 in the Jedi Fighter got his head disconnected by a buzz droid.  He was making little a little wobbly scream as it flew away, so I assumed there was some sentience in there, not just sensors.  But... it _was_ Episode III.  As hard as I try, I can't seem to remove them from my memory...

Comment: @JaneS Nah, you didn't hear the R4 droid scream, because in space, nobody can you hear you scream.

Comment: @RichS I suspect the screams were all the fanboys (and fangirls! ;) ) at just how stupid that movie truly was.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks for the pics showing what it is on (or just inside) the surface of R2's dome, and pointing out that none are essential brain functions. Can you provide sources to show that the brain is not actually in the dome?

Comment: @RichS "x squared... plus a constant!"

Comment: There was one clone wars episode where R2 was dismantled to get at his memory. I think there it was shown where his memory is located at

Comment: @JaneS You can't have heard that, because Obi-wan never owned a droid before, or at least doesn't recall having done so.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta Saying that he never owned a droid before may be true... from a certain point of view...!

Comment: @JaneS if the speaker is in the head, perhaps some power storage, an abrupt disconnection may not cease activity. Ever seen a chicken have its head severed? They keep on moving. Same applies to people, both heads (tongues, eyes) and limbs.

Comment: @JaneS `He was making little a little wobbly scream as it flew away, so I assumed there was some sentience in there, not just sensors.` ...could be sentience or could be like when I unplug my laptop from my speakers and leave the jack plug on a metallic surface and I can hear them "screaming" while I walk away with the laptop. That isn't sentience. I certainly hope not. It's just... a glitch... a noise that... because if not... Oh, my... what if I am a monster...?

Comment: @JaneS Oh, of course it is, if you are a real Star Wars fan, you need to visit every question question and if it mentions anything later than 1983, you absolutely have to loudly complain how much it sucks.

Comment: @Malcolm Me and Star Wars have history :)  I remember reading the original novelisation in 1977 (I was too young to  be allowed to see it in the cinema).  However, I saw both _Empire Strikes Back_ and _Return of the Jedi_ in the cinema (_and_ had the novelisations of both!).   :)

Comment: @RichS There's nothing else canon to indicate that his brain isn't in there. We don't see them repair him, and he's too badly charred too make out parts in ANH

Comment: @JaneS " I suspect the screams were all the fanboys (and fangirls! ;) ) at just how stupid that movie truly was." I find your lack of faith disturbing.

Comment: @JaneS Sorry, are you saying the *bit of head that was blown off* was screaming? (I haven't seen the movie in a while.) Is it actually clear from the scene that it's the *head* that's screaming and not the *body*?

Comment: @KyleStrand I mean the whole head that had been severed by the buzz droid was screaming as it floated off into space. I saw it recently again because my daughter wanted to watch it.

Comment: [The R4 death scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzBZRE-vbtY). For comparison, here's [R2D2 being shot](https://youtu.be/2WBG2rJZGW8?t=751). The best I can say (since we know even less about R4) is that the speaker was projecting the last thing sent to it by the core. For lack of a better term, screaming was the last thing that went through it's head. It does confirm that the speaker is in the head, assuming R2 is built the same way.

Comment: @JaneS Ah, got it! Machavity's link helped. Though I find it a bit weird that there's some important-looking "stuff" sticking up from the head-stump *and* sticking out of the dome itself.